# Erro 'std::out_of_range' ao usar substring C++

Tags: c++, string

Possuo um arquivo `txt` que contém o seguinte tipo de informação em cada linha:

Exemplo:

> João-88888888

Preciso ler cada linha desse arquivo e separar o *nome* em uma variável e o *número* em outra, para isso utilizei o `substring()`, para pegar o nome fiz o seguinte.

```
 while(!temp.eof()){       
        getline(temp, linha); 
        posl = linha.find('-');
        if((linha.substr(0, posl).compare(nome))){
          //faço algo aqui
        }
 }
```

Dessa forma o algoritmo funciona perfeitamente e pego somente o nome que existe na linha e comparo com outra variável e realizo uma operação ali. Porém estou tendo erro quando tento pegar o número. Código:

```
 while(!temp.eof()){
      getline(temp, linha);
      posl = linha.find('-');

      if(linha.substr(posl+1).compare(numero)){ //aqui quebra
           //faço algo
      }
 }
```

O erro é este

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Com mais umas informações. Os tipos de variáveis estão corretos. O que será que está causando isto? Há outra forma mais prática?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em c++, o metodo substr retorna uma exceção out_of_range caso o usuário tente usar o método com valores que são maiores que o tamanho da string (Veja o final da [Referencia c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) sobre o método substr)

Answer (score 1):

Só com estas informações não dá para ajudar muito. Falta partes do código, não temos os dados que produzem isto, nem detalhes do erro.

O código parece estranho nas duas partes mostradas. Por exemplo, o `compare` está usado de um jeito anormal, espero que saiba o que está fazendo. Mas isto não gera este erro.

Provavelmente não está achando o hífen na linha e o `posl` (nome de variável terrível para ler no código, confunde a letra L com o número 1) está valendo um valor muito alto. Quando se soma 1 nele e tenta acessar um dos caracteres, dá esse erro. O valor alto fora da faixa aceitável para este texto foi gerado porque o `find` não achou o que estava procurando.